# How to set up pages for a 11x17" print document

Tags: print-design, paper-size

I have a brochure that will be printed on one 11x17 sheet, then folded in half to get a "4 page" brochure (printing on front and back). Is it better to set up my InDesign document size as 11x17 or should I do letter size facing pages instead? Any pros/cons to either method? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I typically set up 4 8.5x11" pages as spreads - [4,1] then [2,3]. You can then print as individual pages or as spreads.

There are no *absolute solid* rules about this. Using individual pages or full spreads both work. It's more a matter of preference than anything else. Unless.... bleeds are a concern.... [How to create a document with alternating (left and right) master pages without working in spreads?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/85984/how-to-create-a-document-with-alternating-left-and-right-master-pages-without/86063#86063)

Answer (score 1):

If they will also need a web version (for the website, email, etc), its better to set up 4 pages as spreads, as @Scott mentioned, and export pages 2,3,4,1 to generate a normal flowing web version.

If setting up as 2 large sheets 11x17, not so easy to break into a web version.