# Indesign: Reshuffling page spreads after creating new page

Tags: adobe-indesign

In Adobe InDesign, I have an 80+ page document using broken apart spreads in the pages window. I want to add a new page after page 13. Once I create the new page, every page after that is no longer on the correct side of the spread. How do I update the pages to automatically re position the pages. I know how to do this manually, but it would be very time intensive. Please see attached image for what I am trying to accomplish. Thanks!

Screenshot of what I am trying to do:

[image: Screenshot of what I am trying to do]

Comment: Curious.. why split spreads as opposed to non-facing pages? (which would eliminate this issue entirely)

Comment: Yeah, this looks really strange. I can't imagine a situation where this way of ordering the pages is useful. What is the benefit?

Comment: I am guessing I have no idea how to setup a document correctly? I want page numbers to be on the left for left pages and on the right for right pages. How should I set that up?

Comment: You can use the 2pg Parent (master) with a single page document. Just apply the left Parent to even pages and the right Parent to odd pages. Then if you need to reassign Parents, simply highlight a Parent page and use the "Apply Parent to pages.." option in the Pages Panel menu and insert numbers, i.e. 2,4,6,8,10..... Possibly Helpful: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/85984/how-to-create-a-document-with-alternating-left-and-right-master-pages-without

Comment: It seems like inserting numbers for a large book would be super prone to errors and mistakes?